# How to fix exception of FTPClient?

Tags: java, android, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I'm making an Android application which can copy files from server into SDCard using `FTPClient`. I use `FTPClient` class from apache commons library. But the server contains 1000+ files, and when I try to get file names from server I get `SocketException`: "The connection was reset" (I have got 25 file names at this moment). Version of library is 3.0.1. How can I fix it?

Function to recursively getting files:

```
private void getFileNames(String directory, FTPClient client) throws IOException {

    Log.e("directory", "*"+directory+"**********");
    client.changeWorkingDirectory(directory);
    FTPFile[] files=client.listFiles();
    for (FTPFile file:files) {
        client.changeWorkingDirectory(directory);
        if (file.isFile()) {
            ++i;
            Log.e("file", file.getName());
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(file.getName()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {

            if (file.isDirectory()&&(!file.getName().equals("."))&&(!file.getName().equals(".."))) {

                //Log.e("1", file.getLink());
                getFileNames(file.getName(), client);
            }
        }
    }

    Log.e("directory", "**********");
}
```

Code for making FTPClient:

```
   FTPClient client=new FTPClient();
    try {
            client.connect(InetAddress.getByName("ftptestsite.com"));
        boolean result=client.login("ftptest1", "bEWw9eZR");
        //client.completePendingCommand();
        //client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        client.setDataTimeout(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        i=0;
        getFileNames("Power Serve", client);
        button.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        //Log.e("size", String.valueOf(client.listFiles("Power_Serve").length));
        //getFileNames(client.listFiles("Power Serve"));
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("SocketException", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("UnknownHostException", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("IOException", e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: I have edited the code, check it please.

Comment: hm, maybe u can set the socket timeout for the ftpclient object

Comment: I have tried, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the recursion and test if if works for one directory.  I'm not sure if you can use `FTPClient` that way.

By the way, in the recursive call you are passing a file name to which a `changeWorkingDirectory()` won't work. You should also remove the `client.changeWorkingDirectory(directory);` from the loop. Doing this once before the loop is enough.

Comment: Please, tell me - how can I fix my code that it show me tree of files? My code doesn't work, I didn't see it.

Comment: I have made your recommendation and now application works longer, but still make SocketException

Comment: @user1078760: Turn on verbose logging by adding a ProtocolCommandListener: `client.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new
PrintWriter(System.out))); `. Maybe you see a problem there.